# How to include an external javascript file conditionally?

Tags: javascript, include

I have this code:

```
<script src="http://external/js/file/url.js">
</script>
```

I want to do something like this-

```
<script>
if(2>1){
//include http://external/js/file/url.js
}
</script>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This question has been asked before in [Include a Javascript File in another Javascript File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file).
This peice of code may fit what you have been looking for

```
function include(filename)
{
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = filename;
   script.type = 'text/javascript';

   head.appendChild(script)
}
```

if that script does not work, i suggest you to look over and read the post above: [Include a Javascript File in another Javascript File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file).

I hope this helps, it may not be the answer you had been looking for, but it may just help.

Answer (score 5):

You simply load it asynchronously like

```
if(yourCondition==true){
var d = document,
            h = d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
            s = d.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'http://external/js/file/url.js';
    h.appendChild(s);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   if (condition == true) {

      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML += ("<script src=\"http://external/js/file/url.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>");

   }

</script>
```