# JSF - how can I conditionally include an external JavaScript in the head section?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2.2

I need to conditionally include a couple of JavaScript files.
Some are stored locally in my webapp, but one is loaded from an external site.
The JSF page has a few sections surrounded by <h:panelGroup rendered="...">, and one of the sections needs the scripts, but the scripts rely on a part of the section to exist, otherwise they create errors. So I need to include the scripts only when the rendered condition of the corresponding section is met.

- <h:outputScript> will only work for local files, so I need to use <script> for the external one.
- All files must be loaded in , so I can't put a <h:panelGroup rendered="..."> around them
- The local files are provided by someone else
- No JavaScript file needs to be loaded dynamically ... it's "all or none"
- The external file must be loaded before any local one, so the solutions from [How to include an external javascript file conditionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979733/how-to-include-an-external-javascript-file-conditionally) or [Dynamically load a JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/dynamically-load-a-javascript-file) either won't work at all or are unnecessarily complicated

**Edit:**
As proposed by Jasper de Vries, I've tried putting a <c:if> around my <script> tags. I've ended up having two <head> sections in the rendered page. The second <head> (containing the <script> tags) was within the <body> and therefore the scripts were not loaded.

This how I tried it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<ui:composition>
<h:head>
  <c:if test="#{myUIBean.includeScripts}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
  </c:if>
</h:head>

<h:body>
   ...
</h:body>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Any ideas for a simple solution?

Comment: I must be missing something, but can't you simply use JSTL `c:if`?

Comment: Um ... well ... because I've never used JSTL in JSF.

Comment: I've just tried the c:if. It looks like it screws up the ui:composition. I'll edit the question accordingly.